# Open Problems in Random Graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, open-problems, random-graphs

I am a PhD student in mathematics. I'm interested in probabilistic methods in combinatorics and especially random graphs. I am looking for an open problem in this area for my PhD proposal. I know that there are many open problems and conjectures, but I would like to find a "good" problem such that I can get some results during my PhD. It would be very helpful for me if you could suggest a bunch of open problems. Thank you!

Comment: PhD projects should not be sought by some kind of online comparison shopping. Why not pick up a book on random graphs and read some of it and try to understand some of it?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, you're right. I have read several books, papers and ... and have some general ideas for a PhD project, but I would like to know the ideas of expert people!

Comment: Do you have a thesis adviser who can suggest some problems? If not, how will you be supervised if you write a thesis on random graphs?

Comment: @RichardStanley My advisor is not expert in this area, but he has given me this freedom to work on my own interests.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/category/random_graph),
which lists this problem:

---

[image: Bukh]

          

<sup>Due to MO user @BorisBukh.</sup>

---